# Обращение к массиву родительского класса из дочернего в C#

Tags: c#, массивы, наследование

Проблема такова: При обращении к родительскому методу через дочерний,размер массива,который перебирается становится равен 0.

**Сам метод**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

массив почему то равен 0,хотя его инспектор выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**обращение к этому методу**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне не понятно почему через обращение к методу через дочерний класс,массив сбрасывает свои элементы,которые в инспекторе никуда не исчезают...

Это  очень глупая проблема,но всё же...

**Родитель**

```
public class PoolManager : MonoBehaviour
{
private List<Pool> poolOfPools = new List<Pool>();

    public Pool GetPool(string poolName)
    {
        Pool pool = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < poolOfPools.Count; i++)
        {
            if (poolName == poolOfPools[i].name)
            {
                pool = poolOfPools[i];
                return pool;
            }
        }
        return pool;
    }
}
```

**Дочерний класс**

```
public class PlatformsLoader : PoolManager
{
    public string poolName = "Platforms";

    private void Start()
    {
        Pool platformPool = GetPool(poolName);

        foreach(GameObject obj in platformPool.pool)
        {
            GameObject platform = Instantiate(obj, gameObject.transform);
            platform.SetActive(false);
        }

    }  
}
```

**Просто класс Pool**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Pool
{
    public string name;
    public GameObject poolAnchor;
    public PoolType poolType;
    public List<GameObject> pool = new List<GameObject>();
}
public enum PoolType
{
    None = 0,
    Platforms = 1
}
```

На первом скрине виден размер массива...

Comment: Вставьте код в вопрос текстом, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Какой тут класс дочерний, какой родительский? На скриншотах только отрывки методов

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас два разных объекта, унаследованных от одного класса (или кто такой PoolManager_2 вообще?) Так у них будет у каждого свой poolOfPools. Можно попробовать описать poolOfPools  как static, может получится что вы хотите.

Comment: Прошу прощения,изначально выставил не тот скрин инспектора(У меня нет никакого PoolManager_2 )

Comment: В `PoolManager` у вас `poolOfPools = new List<Pool>();`, т.е. действительно изначально количество элементов = 0. Или вы не весь код этого класса показали?

Comment: Этот массив я заполнял через инспектор...На 2 ом скриншоте виден его размер,который равен 2